# Why has my Jenkins stopped responding to BitBucket pushes through Webhooks?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

We have set up Bitbucket to make a call to Jenkins on every push (https://jenkins.MYORG.com/bitbucket-hook/).  It has been working for literally years.  Then at the beginning of February the Jenkins builds stopped being triggered.

Bitbucket is registering each push as a 200 on the call (this is as of Feb 18, 2021):
[image: Push Log]

But the last webhook seen by Jenkins was Feb 3, 2021:

```
Started on Feb 3, 2021 2:50:53 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 77642d1711b318ce5429e6c532661cf74808b724 (refs/remotes/insight/develop)
using credential 6fdd775e-c5fb-4a52-9210-caa8a8bd6671
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials XXX Bitbucket Login
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h -- https://bitbucket.org/XXX/insight.git # timeout=10
Found 100 remote heads on https://bitbucket.org/XXX/insight.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/develop is: 77642d1711b318ce5429e6c532661cf74808b724 - already built by 33
Done. Took 3.9 sec
No changes
```

The Jenkins Branch is set to "*/develop"

And the commit body (please ask if there's anything in tehre that would be helpful) has the following:

```
"new": {
          "name": "develop",
          "links": {
            "commits": {
              "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/xxx/insight/commits/develop"
            },
            "self": {
              "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/xxx/insight/refs/branches/develop"
            },
            "html": {
              "href": "https://bitbucket.org/xxx/insight/branch/develop"
            }
          },
```

So they seem to coincide.  The Repository URL goes directly to the repo in Bitbucket, the credentials are valid, triggers are set to "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket."  I am thoroughly puzzled.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Are you using `bitbucket-server-intergration` Jenkins plugin?

Comment: @hilsenrat - using the Bitbucket plugin, as I have been -  https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was our StackPath did not have all the IP ranges for Bitbucket, so when it switched, we were blocking the push.